# Set height of Google Apps Script showModalDialog when using an HtmlService HtmlTemplate

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm currently in the process of changing over my Google Apps Scripts that use the deprecated UI service to the HtmlService.

I've created a modal dialogue using the following code (in a spreadsheet container-bound script):

```js
var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('testDialogue');

htmlTemplate = template.evaluate().setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);

SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlTemplate, 'Test Dialogue');
```

The dialogue box opens, but I need to modify its dimensions.

HtmlOutput objects have a [setHeight method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setHeight(Integer)), but there doesn't seem to be the same method available for [HtmlTemplate objects](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-template).

I tried using the method anyway on the object like this:

```js
var htmlTemplate = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('testDialogue').setHeight(300);
```

But that produces this error:

> TypeError: Cannot find function setHeight in object HtmlTemplate

Also, I checked the [SpreadsheetApp Ui Class and showModalDialog method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui#showModalDialog(Object,String)) but neither of them seem to have methods for setting the height of HtmlTemplate objects.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The .setHeight() method can be used when chaining it after the .evaulate() method, like so:

```js
template = template.evaluate()
                   .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
                   .setHeight(300);
```

**Update 2/19/19:** The `.setSandboxMode()` method no longer has any effect - now all scripts now use IFRAME mode regardless of what sandbox mode is set ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-output#setsandboxmodemode)). That method was not related to setting the height but I figured I'd mention this in case anyone ends up copying and pasting this code sample.

Comment: Do you have an IFRAME example if Sandbox is 'no longer' valid?

Comment: @aNewb The `setSandboxMode()` method is just not needed anymore. So the working statement would be: `template = template.evaluate().setHeight(300);`